# Removing the division in a GroupBox Header and the main box

Tags: c#, xaml, handycontrol

I think this is a fairly simple question.  If I am using HandyControls to stylize my C#/XAML application, how can I remove the division between the header of a GroupBox and it's content?

I would rather it just be one box, but in HandyControls, they have an example where the header's box doesn't have padding between it and the main content box, which would be acceptable. How could I mimic that style?

Trying to see what I could figure out my self, I saw some example code they had.  In some of the examples they use add a style that changes the GroupBox slightly.  StaticResource GroupBox.Small in the case of what I saw. But it doesn't have the effect I want. Is there other options instead of "Small" that might achieve the effect I want? I couldn't find a list of what was available

I want to say I basically have no experience making my own styles for XAML controls, especially modifying already modified ones. So please take that into consideration.

Comment: If you look at the source for [Groupbox.Small](https://github.com/ghost1372/HandyControls/blob/86ffbc8b2354b96249ac95cc1369a425492b2e88/src/Shared/HandyControl_Shared/Themes/Styles/GroupBox.xaml#L5) and how it modifies [GroupBoxBaseStyle](https://github.com/ghost1372/HandyControls/blob/86ffbc8b2354b96249ac95cc1369a425492b2e88/src/Shared/HandyControl_Shared/Themes/Styles/Base/GroupBoxBaseStyle.xaml#L39), you could adapt it and hopefully create your own custom style.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that to save my life.

Comment: This may be a simple question, but you've presented it poorly. Perhaps read [ask]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the style to GroupBoxTab or GroupBoxTab.Small to get the desired effect.